# retrieve data from firebase in ionic 3 and angular 5

Tags: firebase, ionic3, angular5, angularfire

Pls I need help in retrieving user data from firebase with AngularFireObject on logging in.
I have been able to save data to firebase but having issues retrieving it. Pls someone help out.
Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first you've to configure your AngularFireModule (I think you already do that). `AngularFireModule.initializeApp(FIREBASE_CONFIG)`.

So, is a good way to create a model/service to handle your entities requests with firebase, something like this:

**Model**:

```
export interface Cutom {
  key?: string,
  name: string,
  quantity: number,
  price: number
}
```

**Service**:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Custom } from './../../models/custom.model';

@Injectable()
export class CustomService {

  private customListRef;
  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.customListRef = this.db.list<Custom>('your-endpoint-at-firebase');
  }

  getCustomList() {
    return this.customListRef;
  }

}
```

In **Component** you will use your recently created service:

```
...
export class HomePage implements OnInit {
  // remember to import the correct model
  customList$: Observable<Custom[]>

  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    private customService: CustomListService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.customList$ = this.customService
    .getCustomList()
    .valueChanges();
  }
```

or if you need the metadata too (like the ID):

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.customList$ = this.customService
    .getCustomList()
    .snapshotChanges()
    .pipe(
      map(items => { // this needs to be imported with: import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
        return items.map(a => {
          const data = a.payload.val();
          const key = a.payload.key;
          return {key, ...data};
        });
    }));
  }
...
```

And the finally at your **template**:

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let item of customList$ | async">
   {{item.name}}
</ion-item>
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Am getting an empty result.

Comment: this.userProfile = this.afDatabase.list<UserProfile>(`profile/${user.uid}`);
  return this.userProfile; How can I introduce profile/${user.uid} so i can fetch the data per user. thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, do you need this information for what? Data editation? I've changed my answer a little bit, maybe it helps you, with `snapshotChanges` instead of `valueChanges` we can retrieve the ID from firebase too.

Comment: I'm happy that have helped you! You can accept my answer as correct please? :)